# Unity3D - Error: The minSdk version can not be specified in the AndroidManifest.xml file. You have to remove it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build.gradle, android-manifest, android-min-sdk

****Build Error appears in Pop Up.****

```
Gradle Error: MinSDK in Manifest

The minSdk version can not be specified in the AndroidManifest.xml file. You have to remove it.
(See the Console for details)
```

**Build Errors appear in console**

```
> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.



Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:lintVitalRelease'.



UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002be] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

**Picture of some errors I couldn't copy.**
[image: Console errors, click to view]

**in essence:**
I have tried reinstalling/Updating JAVA.
I have tried removing `minsdk` line from `AndroidManifext.xml`
I have tried all possible solutions available on internet but remained with same error.
Please Help to resolve this I want the build.

**AndroidManifest.xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
   WARNING: Do NOT modify! Generated file.
-->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__AndroidManifest_Package__"
    android:versionCode="__AndroidManifest_VersionCode__"
    android:versionName="__AndroidManifest_VersionName__">
    
    <uses-sdk 
   
        android:targetSdkVersion="__AndroidManifest_TargetSdkVersion__"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you share your manifest file? I think the problem is there.

Comment: okay I have updated the question and added it.

Comment: As far as I could remember (I don't have a Unity project by hand right now), `AndroidManifest.xml` could come from plugins. If you do use some plugins, maybe you could search for the manifest in your project and see if any other plugins use the minSdk atrribute.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your problem, but here is my manifest file that works for me. you can try this. be sure to set your package name in line 4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
      package="com.test.test" 
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<supports-screens 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:xlargeScreens="true" 
android:anyDensity="true" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" 
           android:label="@string/app_name" 
           android:debuggable="true" 
           android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" 
           android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
  <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>   
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
</activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: it didn't worked